React updating a value in a mapped object from child component
using React I've been able to update a value of an object stored in the parent component from a onChange() made in a child component.
However I'm trying to do the same with a component that is created from a list of mapped objects, so it only updates the value in the object list that built that component. I'm failing but here's an example of what I'm doing:
Parent Component:


const Parent = () => {
  const [banners, bannersUpdate] = React.useState([
    {
      id: 1, name: "banner1", nameSize: 14
    },
    {
      id: 2, name: "banner2", nameSize: 16
    },
    {
      id: 3, name: "banner3", nameSize: 18
    }
  ]);
  
  
  const handleUpdateNameSize = (id, e) => {
    banners.nameSize = e.value
    bannersUpdate({
        nameSize: banners.nameSize,
        ...banners
    })
  }
  
  
  return(
    <section className="banners">
      {banners.map(banner =>
        <Banner 
          key={banner.id}
          id={banner.id}
          name={banner.name}
          nameSize={banner.nameSize}
          updateNameSize={handleUpdateNameSize}
        />
      )}
    </section>
  );
}



Child component:


const Banner = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="banCont">
      <h2 style={{fontSize: props.nameSize + 'px'}}>{props.name}</h2>
      <input onChange={(e) => props.updateNameSize(props.id, e.target)}  className={'slider1-' + props.name} />
    </div>
  )
}



With the above it doesn't update the object item relating to that banner, it instead just adds a new object item at the top level with that name and value.
I believe the answer relies somewhere in using the key and I've tried replacing all the banners with banners[id] like: banners[id].nameSize = e.value but for some reason it's not working to update the value.
Help would be appreciated please, thanks.

btw you wont access key as a prop on the other side. also banners.nameSize = e.value is strange, what exactly are you trying to do there

@cmgchess I will update the OP as I did also notice that error message in the React Component Console and tried passing the same value as an ID prop to use, but it still doesn't work.

what exactly are you tryint to update there. what is nameSize relation with the e.value which the value you are typing in the input. is it the input length?

I've updated the OP to pass & use an id prop, that nameSize value is to increase/decrease with a range type input in each banner created, that will then be used to set the font-size of text in a name element in each relating banner created. Any help would be great to achieve this?

yeah but what isnt clear is what is set to nameSize in the update call. say i type "Hello" in banner1 input then what should be set to nameSize

Okay for a better understanding of the end goal, I've actually built the whole tool in Vue here: https://codepen.io/Chobbit/pen/ExrmPWr, however I'm trying to adapt to React by building it again in React. So you can see the user will enter a name in the left panel and it will update in all the banners on the right. In Vue you simply use v-model and things to link up the range input and the style stuff you want to change. Hope this helps show more what I want to achieve here, thanks.

your updating function has some issues. First banners.nameSize = e.value you are trying to add a nameSize "field" to your banners "array". Instead what you should do is to find the relevant banner using the id and update its nameSize value.
Also as the other answer mentions as well. Use map to ensure that the state is changed and the component re-renders. Using a find by the id and then updating the nameSize field will mutate the state and will not cause a re-render
Also better to follow naming standards for useState updating function. if state is banners then the function name like setBanners


const Banner = ({id, name, nameSize, updateNameSize}) => {
  return (
    <div className="banCont">
      <h2 style={{fontSize: nameSize + 'px'}}>{name}</h2>
      <input onChange={(e) => updateNameSize(id, e.target)}  className={'slider1-' + name} />
    </div>
  )
}

const Parent = () => {
    const [banners, setBanners] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, name: "banner1", nameSize: 14 },
    { id: 2, name: "banner2", nameSize: 16 },
    { id: 3, name: "banner3", nameSize: 18 }
  ]);
  
  const handleUpdateNameSize = (id, e) => {
     const nameSize = e.value.length;
     setBanners(prevBanner => prevBanner.map(banner => banner.id === id ? { ...banner, nameSize } : banner))
  }
  
  return(
    <div style={{display:'flex'}}>
      <section className="banners">
        {banners.map(banner =>
          <Banner 
            key={banner.id}
            id={banner.id}
            name={banner.name}
            nameSize={banner.nameSize}
            updateNameSize={handleUpdateNameSize}
          />
        )}
      </section>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(banners, null, 2)}</pre>
    </ div>
  );
};


const App = () => {
  return (
     <Parent />
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>




Thank you for the information it helps alot to understand better, I only started learning React after Vue and there;s definetly some new things to learn. I will try adapting this answer in and feedback but it looks promising thank you for the effort and response.

I really wanted to mark this as the answer, you answered first and I really liked you explaining the useState standards, with a little adjusting I was able to get your example working in my app (and having a working example in your code was nice). I however had to make the odd change to get it working, like changing ? { ...banner, nameSize } : banner) to ? { ...banner, nameSize: e } : banner) and (e) => updateNameSize(id, e.target)} to(e) => props.updateNameSize(props.id, e.target.value). I decided just to mark abuzain's answer as it needed no changes to work but it was very close.
